# Graph API in SSO is not working in Azure AD

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to develop a Java web application with SSO by following this [azure tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java/). I created an account in Azure and created an AD. Developed and deployed the code in Tomcat. When I try to access the page, I am getting the following error

```
Exception - java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://graph.windows.net/ppceses.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=2013-04-05
```

I do not find enough answers for this error. I changed the api-version to 1.6. Even then it did not work.

**MORE ANALYSIS:**

After troubleshooting, I found out that the logged-in user info is fetched and is available in Sessions object. It errors out when its trying to read the response and convert into the String object. Following is the calling method where it errors out.

```
HttpClientHelper.getResponseStringFromConn(conn, true);
```

Actual method to write the response into String:

```
public static String getResponseStringFromConn(HttpURLConnection conn, boolean isSuccess) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    if (isSuccess) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    } else {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
    }
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

The actual issue is on the Graphic API where we try to read the response in the String format.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Paul, I moved onto other project as its got low priority. To answer your question, No. I will work on this when I get chance to. Do you have solution?

Comment: In my case granting directory.readAll and group.readAll permission worked.

Answer (score 1):

@Anand, According to [Microsoft Graph error responses and resource types](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/errors), the response code 403 means **`Forbidden`** below.

> Access is denied to the requested resource. The user might not have enough permission.

Please move to the `CONFIGURE` tab of your application registered in your AAD domain on Azure classic portal,  then check whether enable enough permission, please see the figure below.

[image]

Comment: I followed your instructions. I selected all options except first one. Even then it did not work. I am still getting the same error. Should I need to change the api version? I am using this URL - https://graph.windows.net/ppceses.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=2013-04-05. Please advise

Comment: same problem as well, I have enable permission for all options but im still getting 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, been struggling with it a few days. What I noticed was that even if I checked ALL permissions for Windows Azure Active Directory I still got the 403. So, I deleted the app in App Registrations and created it again from scratch, generated new application key and readded reply urls. In Required Permissions/Windows Azure Active Directory check:

- Sign in and read user profile
- Access the directory as the signed-in user

I can now call `me/memberOf` successfully.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me.
At the active directory app registrations -> app ->settings->permissions-> enable delegate permissions to read directory data. Save and close the blade. Also Click Grant Permissions and close the blade.
Once the above is done, Log out and Log in back with a fresh token to the application. (Guess the token with prior authorizations will not reflect the latest permission changes and hence the re-login may have worked in my case)